# Search for words in hyperlink Python 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a python 3 script to scrape a website and check if the producct is in stock. The issue I am having is searching for the product name in the hyperlink I am grabbing from BeautifulSoup. The product name will have a space, so it is actually 2 words and I think thats what is causing the issue.

** product_name is passed in, example: "Blue Truck"
example link: `<a href="https://example.com/products/">Blue Truck</a>`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print("Trying to find links " + threadName)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
     if product_name in a['href']:
        email_link(a)
        print("FOUND" + threadName)
        break
     elif product_name.lower() in a['href']:
        email_link(a)
        print("FOUND" + threadName)
        break
```

When running this code, it never returns a match. I also tried:

```
 if (a.find(product_name) != -1):
    email_link(a)
```

This find() returned false matches. Any help would be great or advice on which way is the fastest.

Comment: Try a.text not a[‘href’]

Answer (score 0):

The `a` tag `"<a href="https://example.com/products/">Blue Truck</a>` has the following attributes:

- `href`: "https://example.com/products/"
- `innerHTML` or `text`: Blue Truck

The code is looking for `a['href']` which is `"https://example.com/products/"`. You want to look for `a.text` which is `Blue Truck`

Answer (score 0):

You should implement something like below:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.parse

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print("Trying to find link for " + thread_name)
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if (product_name.lower() in a.text.lower()) or (urllib.parse.quote(product_name.lower()) in a['href']): # can also add regex
        email_link(a)
        print("FOUND" + thread_name)
        break
```